# DataBind DataSource Result to ASP Labels

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, data-binding

I have an AccessDataSource `TestSummaryADS`.  I can easily view the results in a GridView or DropDownList by setting its DataSourceID property.

How do I bind a value from the results `TestSummaryADS` to the text of a label?

I'm just trying to populate labels on my page with results from the DB entry.

C# or VB.NET answers okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have a single record, use a `FormView`

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormViewTestSummary" runat="server" 
DataSourceID="TestSummaryADS"
DefaultMode="Edit">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <fieldset>           
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMyText" Text='<%# Bind("ProjectNumber") %>' runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Repeater` control that contains Label controls to display the values you want. Bind your DataSource control to the repeater.

Also you can use `TemplateColumn` with GridView and add your labels into this template column.

But IMO, Repeater control is simpler to customize your view by templates.